# d3.js: Expand multiple paths in tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My JSON contains same node names in different paths, I would like to be able to open all children with the same name or has substring in their names.

Tried this example: [[Search Collapsible Tree](https://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950)], but it opens only one path.
The idea is to implement search for substring and a if a path has a node that contains the search term, then, open (expand) that path.
So, I replaced the Select2 to text input but the search is still limited to one result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change tree search function to find all the nodes (and then, highlight everything):

```js
 function searchTree(obj,search,path, paths){
  if(obj.name.indexOf(search) != -1){ //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
   path.push(obj);
   paths.push(path.slice(0)); // clone array
  }
  else if(obj.children || obj._children){ //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
   var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
   for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one     
    searchTree(children[i],search,path, paths);
    path.pop();
   }
  }
 }

...

 $("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
  var paths = [];
  searchTree(root,e.object.text,[], paths);
  if(paths.length > 0)
  {
   paths.forEach(function(p) { openPaths(p) });
   //openPaths(paths);
  }
  else{
   alert(e.object.text+" not found!");
  }
 })
```